# How do I override the couchbase query timeout in aws glue job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, couchbase, aws-glue, sql++

I'm trying to run a Couchbase query in an aws glue job, using the [spark couchbase connector](https://docs.couchbase.com/spark-connector/current/working-with-rdds.html). My query is a simple N1Ql query against the existing Couchbase bucket:

```
var queryResultRDD: RDD[CouchbaseQueryRow] = spark.sparkContext.couchbaseQuery(N1qlQuery.simple(CbN1qlQuery))
```

If I have a long running query, I receive the following error message:

```
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.java.error.QueryExecutionException: Timeout 1m15s exceeded
at com.couchbase.spark.connection.QueryAccessor$$anonfun$compute$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$4.apply(QueryAccessor.scala:56)
at com.couchbase.spark.connection.QueryAccessor$$anonfun$compute$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$4.apply(QueryAccessor.scala:53)
at rx.lang.scala.Observable$$anon$32.call(Observable.scala:1324)
```

The 1m15s timeout setting likely comes from [Couchbase's 75s default query timeout](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/ref/client-settings.html#timeout-options), so I tried to [add the query timeout setting directly](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-spark-connector-2.4.0/com/couchbase/spark/SparkContextFunctions.html#couchbaseQuery(query:com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlQuery,bucketName:String,timeout:Option%5Bscala.concurrent.duration.Duration%5D):com.couchbase.spark.rdd.QueryRDD) to the query call hoping that it would override the default timeout setting:

```
var queryResultRDD: RDD[CouchbaseQueryRow] = sc.couchbaseQuery(N1qlQuery.simple(CbN1qlQuery), "bucket-name", Some(Duration(130, SECONDS)))
```

Dropping that duration down to something impossibly low like 1 ms resulted in a different query timeout error. However, if I made the duration longer as shown above I still received the same QueryExecutionException where the timeout was still 1m15s. I also tried to set the System Property in the Glue job script:

```
System.setProperty("com.couchbase.env.timeout.queryTimeout", "1ms")
```

Yet I still received the same 1m15s timeout error. I also tried setting the `spark.couchbase.timeout.queryTimeout` property in the same way and got the same result. I also tried setting the query timeout configuration in the sparkSession builder with no change:

```
    val Spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName(DefaultName)
  .config("spark.couchbase.nodes", CbNodes)
  .config(s"spark.couchbase.bucket.$SourceBucketName", SourceBucketPassword)
  .config("spark.couchbase.username", SourceBucketUserName)
  .config("spark.couchbase.password", SourceBucketPassword)
  .config("spark.ssl.enabled", CbSslEnabled)
  .config("spark.ssl.keyStore", CbKeyStore)
  .config("spark.ssl.keyStorePassword", CbKeyStorePassword)
  .config("spark.couchbase.timeout.queryTimeout", "1ms")
  .getOrCreate()
```

How do I override this 1m15s query timeout setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after looking at the [CouchbaseConfig class](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-spark-connector/blob/2.3.0/src/main/scala/com/couchbase/spark/connection/CouchbaseConfig.scala) what the config is supposed to be:

```
.config("com.couchbase.queryTimeout", "10")
```

where the querytimeout value is in ms.